# function test value in a range of values and return value

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I'm new to clojure script and I'm trying to cover the following function into clojurescript

```
function getLengthAtPoint(pt){
        var i = 0;
    while(i < p.getTotalLength())
    {
        var xy = p.getPointAtLength(i);
      // console.log(i, xy);
        if(Math.round(xy.y) == pt[1] && Math.round(xy.x) == pt[0])
      {
            return i;
      }

      i++;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

I have the following logic

```
(defn get-length-at-point
  [p pt]
  (doseq [
     i (range (.getTotalLength p))
    :let [xy (.getPointAtLength p i)]
    :when (and (= (round js/Math (first xy)) (first pt)) (= (round js/Math (last xy)) (last pt)))]
    i)
  0)
```

But I think I maybe wrong here because :when will not return `i` will it?

**Update**

---

Came up with this

```
(defn get-length-at-point
  [pt {p :path}]
  (loop [i 0]
    (let [point (.getPointAtLength p i)]
    (cond
       (and (= (.round js/Math (.-x point)) (.round js/Math (:x pt)))
       (= (.round js/Math (.-y point)) (.round js/Math (:y pt)))) i
       (>= i (.getTotalLength p)) 0
        :else (recur (inc i))
       ))))
```

If someone knows a simpler way please share

Comment: Your Javascript refers to `p` and `pt`, though only `pt` is a parameter.

Comment: yeah I'm adding some additional stuff in the clojure version

Comment: Does the Javascript `getLengthAtPoint`, as written above, actually work? Since the body of the function operates on an undefined variable `p`, this seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what you're trying to calculate here, but this is some of the way towards what you're after:

```
(defn get-length-at-point
  [pt p]
  (->> (map #(.getPointAtLength p %) (range (.getTotalLength p)))
       (filter (fn [point] (and (= (.round js/Math (.-x point)) (.round js/Math (:x pt)))
                                (= (.round js/Math (.-y point)) (.round js/Math (:y pt))))))
       (count)))
```

Idiomatic Clojure code usually avoids `loop` where a `map` will do. `doseq` is run only for side effects, and won't return a value to you. Most of the time, Clojure code also doesn't use indexes. If you update the post with more context for what you're trying to do, and what functions you can call on `p`, we might be able to help more.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would have been obvious via the Javascript. p is a `<path>` element and I'm trying to get the length at a given point( opp. of `getPointAtLength`)